# HP ProLiant ML350p - when does a status code indicate an actual issue even when iLO does not mention any?

Tags: hp-proliant, boot, ilo

I've recently purchased the above mentioned server. It boots fine, it even has a Windows 10 installed on it (unknown password, will replace with RHLE anyway). iLO4 doesn't show any issues at all (except the infamous problem **Embedded Flash/SD-CARD: Embedded media manager failed initialization** that I'm looking forward to fixing) and yet every time after powering on the server I get all kinds of status codes:

```
0114
4165
4048
0160
4078
5300
5808
```

in this order (as far as I remember).

Searching online reveals all possible issues.

**Example:** 0114 is supposed to have something to do with the RAM DIMMs not being compatible and/or bad. However iLO4's diagnostics shows full memory size (32GB per CPU in a dual CPU setup) and every module is with a healthy status.

Since I am yet to make my setup (RHLE with KVM) I want to make sure that the bare metal is actually ok before I go on installing stuff.

**Note:** I have update iLO4 FW from 2.70 (was on the server when I bought it) to 2.78.

Comment: I guess those are the BIOS POST codes (meant for troubleshooting). If the boot process freezes at a certain code, you can look up this code to determine, what causes the freeze. As long as they change, they don't claim failures but show the currently running test. Regarding the "embedded SD" issue: you can try to reformat (it sometimes helps), but be prepared for a motherboard replacement.

Comment: I formatted the embedded flash/SD-card controller and the issue is no longer listed in iLO.

Is there a list of all the status codes somewhere? I tried [here](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c01702138) but this is not it. I want an official source and not forum posts because right now this is all it boils down to.